# Replacing variable length string with some word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Given the below string

```
Declare @string varchar(max)='abc ___________ deffns ___ cg _ hif _______hh ihs';
```

**this is the Output required :**  (Every hypen irrespective of length should be replaced with lastname)

```
abc lastname deffns lastname cg lastname hif lastname hh ihs
```

The issue here is, there can be many `Hypens` of variable length(max length can be <20)...

I tried with **many** methods and settled with below approach..

```
select 
REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(stringcol,replicate('_',20),'LASTNAME'),
replicate('_',19),'LASTNAME'),
replicate('_',18),'LASTNAME')
 from table
```

Is there a way to do accomplish this efficiently..any advice would be most welcome

Comment: what should the output look like for the string shown? do you want to replace the first series of `_` before `def`?

Comment: @vkp:please see updated

Comment: In your example, would you expect LASTNAME to appear after abc AND after def?

Comment: @Tyron78:Every hypen irrespective of length should be replaced with lastname

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First get rid of the multiple underscores, then do the replace.

Here is one method:

```
select replace(replace(replace(@string, '_', '><'
                              ), '<>', ''
                      ), '><', 'LASTNAME'
              )
```

Comment: At first glance I thought ... "Meh. Nothing special".  Then I saw the logic of expansion, reduction, and remainder.   Simply brilliant and a truly elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can use:

```
string str = Regex.Replace(s, @"(_)\1{5,}", Lastname);
```

It will match character _ if more than 5 _ occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip