# SQL String: Counting Words inside a String

Tags: sql-server, string

I searched through many of the questions here but all I found with decent answer is for different language like Javascript etc.

I have a simple task in SQL that I can't seem to find a simple way to do.
I just need to count the number of "words" inside a SQL string (a sentence). You can see why "words" is in quotes in my examples. The "words" are delimited by white space.

Sample sentences:

```
1. I am not your father.
2. Where are your brother,sister,mother?
3. Where are your brother, sister and mother?
4. Who are     you?
```

Desired answer:

```
1. 5
2. 4
3. 7
4. 3
```

As you can see, I need to count the "words" disregarding the symbols (I have to treat them as part of the word). So in sample no. 2:
`(1)Where (2)are (3)your (4)brother,sister,mother? = 4`

I can handle the multiple whitespaces by doing a replace like this:
`REPLACE(string, '  ', ' ') -> 2 whitespaces to 1
REPLACE(string, '   ', ' ') -> 3 whitespaces to 1 and so on..`

What SQL function can I use to do this? I use SQL Server 2012 but needs a function that works in SQL Server 2008 as well.

Comment: This is a hairy problem if you ask me.  For example, suppose you had the number `3,000` appear as one of the words.  Then, in this case, splitting on comma wouldn't be correct.  You should clearly tell us what the rules are here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the comma or any other special character is to be treated as part of the "word". It is stated in my question. The only valid delimiter that it will cater is a single whitespace.

Comment: Does it have to be done in SQL? :|

Comment: @Azola Agreed, I'd much rather do this in Java or .NET.

Comment: SQL is *not* a text manipulation language. Why are you trying to do that with SQL at all? *Maybe* you could use full text search, since it understands words and punctuations.

Comment: @Azola unfortunately, yes. I know SQL string manipulation is a bit hard in sql but I assume there is something I can use to accomplish this simple task.

Comment: @super-user not hard, bad. SQL is a query language and this is not a query. Isolating words is part of FTS. If you really need to use SQL, calculate the words when *loading* the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand. I can easily do this with .net and javascript but the project Im developing requires string manipulation through SQL and I cannot really do much to oppose it.

Comment: @super-user you can use SQLCLR to write an appropriate function or that uses Regexp to quickly count words **WITHOUT** generating temporary strings. Each `REPLACE` is going to generate strings, probably lead to bad execution plans too.

Comment: As for SQL Server 2008 - it's no longer supported. 2012 is the earliest version. 2016 offers a `STRING_SPLIT` function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Someone has answered with what I'm looking for.Thank you for the useful information brother.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using SQLCLR does come with an overhead... I wonder it it would really do better then the brilliant 3 replaces  method Gordon have shown.

Comment: @ZoharPeled what overhead? It's the same SQLOS, same memory management but *NO* parsing, no temporary strings. 3 replacements create 3 temp strings and you still have no count. A regex generates only integer pointers to the matches. Count them and you are done. There are even faster methods [working with characters](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/28/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable.aspx). In fact, only 2016's `STRING_SPLIT` is [faster than SQLCLR](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Perhaps I'm wrong, or my knowledge about CLR is outdated, I seem to remember reading about an overhead when using CLR, but that was a long time ago.

Comment: @ZoharPeled it's actually a misconception, or confusion due to bad coding - a String.Split is bad for perf even in desktop applications. SQLOS was responsible for memory management from the start. Just check the benchmarks and remember that features like HierachyId, Spatial types *are* SQLCLR types

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save is this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    string varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('I am not your father.'),
('Where are your brother,sister,mother?'),
('Where are your brother, sister and mother?'),
('Who are     you?')
```

Use a cte to replace multiple spaces to a single space (Thanks to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875256/3094533))

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  Id,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(string, ' ', '><' -- Note that there are 2 spaces here
                               ), '<>', ''
                       ), '><', ' '
                ) as string
FROM @T
)
```

Query the CTE - length of the string - length of the string without spaces + 1:

```
SELECT id, LEN(string) - LEN(REPLACE(string, ' ', '')) + 1 as CountWords
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
id  CountWords
1   5
2   4
3   7
4   3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Nicely done and simple. May I ask why the + 1 is required to make it work correctly?

Comment: Because the [length of the string] - [the length of the strings without delimiters] returns the number of the delimiters. To get the number of values, you need to add one.

Comment: @ZoharPeled this is a good answer. However it will count empty string as one word

Answer (score 3):

This is a minor improvement of @ZoharPeled's answer. This can also handle 0 length values:

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE(id int identity(1,1), string varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
  ('I am not your father.'),
  ('Where are your brother,sister,mother?'),
  ('Where are your brother, sister and mother?'),
  ('Who are     you?'),
  ('')

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    Id,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(string,' ', '><'), '<>', '') string
  FROM @t
)
SELECT 
  id,
  LEN(' '+string)-LEN(REPLACE(string, '><', ' ')) CountWords
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple spaces too, use the method shown here

```
Declare @s varchar(100)
set @s='Who are     you?'
set @s=ltrim(rtrim(@s))

while charindex('  ',@s)&gt;0
Begin
    set @s=replace(@s,'  ',' ')
end

select len(@s)-len(replace(@s,' ',''))+1 as word_count
```

https://exploresql.com/2018/07/31/how-to-count-number-of-words-in-a-sentence/

Answer (score 0):

I found this query more useful than the first. it omit extra characters and numbers and symbols, so it would count just words within a passage...

```
drop table if exists #t
create table #t (id int identity(1,1), c1 varchar(2000))
insert into #t (c1) 
values 
('Alireza Sattarzadeh Farkoush '),
('yes it is the   best .'),
('abc def ghja a the . asw'),
('?>< 123 ...!  z a b'),
('Wallex is   the greatest exchange in the .. world a after binance ...!')

select c1 , Count(*)
from (
select id, c1, value  
from #t t
cross apply (
select rtrim(ltrim(value)) as value from string_split(c1,' ')) a 
where len(value) > 1 and value like '%[a-Z]%' 
) Final 
group by c1
```

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2016, you can use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) to accomplish this easily. Filtering out empty values avoids counting extra rows from consecutive delimiters.

```
SELECT COUNT([value])
FROM STRING_SPLIT('Where are your brother, sister and mother?', ' ')
WHERE [value] <> ''

SELECT COUNT([value])
FROM STRING_SPLIT('Who are     you?', ' ')
WHERE [value] <> ''
```

Results:

```
7
3
```